# How to call asynchronous Javascript functions from Unity scripts?

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have been trying to follow Unity's documentation for creating JavaScript files/functions so that I can get access to the web browsers apis to interface with the browsers JavaScript engine. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html

I am making a Unity 2d game for WebGL platforms and I want to have users be able to connect their MetaMask wallet and get access to their wallet addresses through MetaMasks api.

Following the documentation, I created a `.jslib` file in my `/Assets/Plugins` directory, that has the following function inside

```
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {

  GetMetaMaskWallet: async function (x, y) {
    const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (err.code === 4001) {
        // EIP-1193 userRejectedRequest error
        // If this happens, the user rejected the connection request.
        console.log('Please connect to MetaMask.');
      } else {
        console.error(err);
      }
    });
    const account = accounts[0];
    return account;
  },
  
});
```

Inside my Unity project, I have a empty game object with a C# script attached, that takes in a Button and attaches a click event listener to it. This click event function, calls the JavaScript function I have above

```
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern string GetMetaMaskWallet();


    public Button connectMetaMaskButton;

    void Start () 
    {
        // 'Connect with MetaMask button'
        Button btn = connectMetaMaskButton.GetComponent<Button>();
        btn.onClick.AddListener(ConnectWallet);
    }

    void ConnectWallet()
    {
    string account = GetMetaMaskWallet();

        if (account != "") {
            connectMetaMaskButton.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
```

For some reason, async functions do not seem to work in returning their expected values. When I `Build and Run` the WebGL project, and click the Connect with MetaMask button, the MetaMask prompt pops up and everything works as expected, but nothing seems to be returning back to my C# script.

I verified that async JS functions are not returning anything by copying some of the examples provided in the Unity docs, for example the:

```
AddNumbers: function (x, y) {
    return x + y;
},
```

and turning it to:

```
AddNumbers: async function (x, y) {
    return x + y;
},
```

This causes nothing to return. I am aware the AddNumbers example makes no sense in being an async function, but testing removing the `async` makes the function work and return the appropriate number I am expecting back to my C# script.

Does anyone have some insight or guidance on how I could get my MetaMask example working, or help on what i am doing wrong with async functions in my JavaScript examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity doesn't wait result of async JavaScript functions. To get the result, you can use 2 ways:

**1. function [SendMessage](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html).** This is the recommended way by Unity.

in **index.html** add myGameInstance declaration:

```js
var myGameInstance = null;
...
createUnityInstance(canvas, config, (progress) =>
    {...}).then((unityInstance) => {
        myGameInstance = unityInstance;
...
```

**Unity:**

```c#
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class AsyncWrapper : MonoBehaviour
{
   [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void AddNumbers(int x, int y);
    
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.Log("Start calculate");
            AddNumbers(100, 200);
        }
    }
    
    public void ShowResult(int value)
    {
        Debug.Log("result by message:" + value);
    }
}
```

Add AsyncWrapper script in scene with "AsyncWrapper" as name of GameObject.

**Javascript**:

```js
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
  AddNumbers: async function (x, y) {
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
      myGameInstance.SendMessage('AsyncWrapper', 'ShowResult', x + y);
    },
});
```

**2. Use callbacks and dynamic function call from Javascript:**

**Unity:**

```c#
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using AOT;
using UnityEngine;

public class AsyncWrapper : MonoBehaviour
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate void intCallback(int value);
    
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void AddNumbers(int x, int y,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] intCallback result);
    
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Debug.Log("Start calculate");
            AddNumbers(100, 200, ShowResult);
        }
    }

    [MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(intCallback))]
    private static void ShowResult(int value)
    {
        Debug.Log("result:" + value);
    }
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```js
mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
  AddNumbers: async function (x, y, onSuccess) {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    dynCall_vi(onSuccess, x + y);
  },
});
```